# how to simply check if record has a specific category in bolt/twig

Tags: bolt-cms

I nedd to check if record belongs to specific category "dogs".
Is there some simple twig statement to do so?
something like {% if 'dogs' in record %} or {% if record.category == 'dogs' %}

I cannot really find my way trought this, thnx

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is `{% if 'dogs' in record.category %}`

Comment: Yes, thanks. Exactly {% if 'dogs' in record.taxonomy.categories %}